# can't template select2 plugin accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i need to template the jquery Select2 plugin results, but i can't seem to get my custom variables to be recognized.
my Select2 configuration:

```
$('.idWorker').select2(
    {
       templateResult: formatWorker  
    }
);
```

My formatWorker function:

```
function formatWorker (worker) {
console.log(worker);
var markup = worker.id+'<p>'+
worker.name+'<p>'+
worker.available+'<p>';
return markup;
}
```

PHP that generates workers data:

```
public function get($id = null)
{
    if($id != null)
    $this->db->where("id = {$id}");
    $query = $this->db->get('worker');
    if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

PHP that generates select2 data:

```
public function customSelect2()
{
    $array = array();
    foreach ($this->get() as $worker)
    {
       $this->db->select("count(tkal.id) as resultcount from token_allocate tkal
        left join worker w on w.id = tkal.idWorker
        where tkal.idWorker = {$worker->id}");
        $query = $this->db->get()->result()[0];
        $available = ($query->resultcount >= 1) ? "this person has been called to attend to {$query->resultcount} tokens" : 'this person is available';
       $array[] = array('id' => $worker->id,'name' => $worker->name, 'available' => $available); 
    }
    return $array;
}
```

that's the strange part, in my js console log, for each worker it prints the following:

```
Object {selected: false, disabled: false, text: "22", id: "id", title: ""…}
Object {selected: false, disabled: false, text: "Moisés Adriano Lago de   Almeida", id: "name", title: ""…}
Object {selected: false, disabled: false, text: "this person is available", id: "available", title: ""…}
```

Why does it create 3 objects for each one and single work in database? i mean, look at what my console prints about the formatWorker function.

AND

Why i cant use the variables that i set in php like this?

```
var markup = worker.id+'<p>'+
worker.name+'<p>'+
worker.available+'<p>';
return markup;
```

Comment: The select2 box looks like this when im done:</br>Foreach worker it prints this:<br/>undefined<p>undefined<p>undefined<br/>Id<p>undefined<p>undefined <br/>name<p>undefined<p>undefined <br/>available<p>undefined<p>undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what is being displayed in the console, it appears that you are not setting up your `<select>` properly. This is possibly because of how the arrays are converted into `<option>` tags, which doesn't appear to be how your are expecting it.

You are creating the array as

```
array(
    'id' => $worker->id,
    'name' => $worker->name,
    'available' => $available
);
```

Which appears to be creating the following set of `<option>` tags.

```
<option value="id">$worker->id</option>
<option value="name">$worker->name</option>
<option value="available">$available</option>
```

So based on that, it should become clear that each index in the array is being transformed into an `<option>`, which is why you are seeing three options per worker being logged to the console.

Now, you are clearly looking for a single `<option>` per worker, and you are expecting the `id` to be sent back on the server side later. So a possible `<option>` tag for each worker might be

```
<option value="$worker-id">$worker->name ($available)</option>
```

Which is easily possible to do with the array in PHP.

```php
$worker_array = array();
$worker_array[$worker->id] = $worker->name . " (" . $available . ")";
$array[] = $worker_array;
```

And depending on what framework you are using for creating the `<option>` tags, you might be able to attach `data-*` attribute on them, which could allow you to have an option that looked like

```
<option value="$worker->id" data-available="$available">$worker->name</option>
```

And your `templateResult` function would only have to look like

```
function formatWorker (obj) {
  var available = obj.element ? $(obj.element).data('available') : '';
  return obj.id + '<p>' + obj.text + '<p>' + available;
}
```

Otherwise you are going to have to parse the last set of parentheses out of `obj.text` to figure out what the name and status is.

Comment: i have little time right now, your answer really helped me but i had to change it a bit so as soon as possible ill be back to thank you a proper way.